# Stick header of listview below any view android

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

Here I am attaching one image displaying what i want to achieve.

[image]

Now, what i want to do is, when the scrollview scrolls upwards, its should scroll the "somedata" "header" and "listview" part behind the image. I have already achieve this.

Next thing should be done is when "header" comes exactly below the "Imageview" while scrolling, it should stick there and then we must be able to scroll the other items of listview.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can not use ListView inside ScrollView. 
You can combine your "Some data" and "header" into single layout and set whole layout as your listview HeaderView.This will make your list scrollable with header.

Comment: But my "header" should be stick below "imageview" when scrolling listview